# Android 9 recent apps... How to make them reasonable?

Tags: 9.0-pie, recents-screen

I upgraded my phone to Android 9/Pie and I can't stand the 'new improved' recent apps list which takes ages to scroll through.

My phone is Motorola G6.

What is the easiest and surefire way to get the old style (or some other style, e.g grid) back?

From what I've searched, it seems pretty complicated.

Either uninstalling the stock launcher using ADB - but I'm not sure if this makes a difference on my phone (people report it works on OnePlus, Pixels and Samsungs).

The other option I found is this https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-quickswitch-universal-quickstep-t3884797/ but I have no clue where to start with that, and it's clearly stated this method does not work with Nova Launcher which I'm using.

I'm not afraid to mod the phone safely but if it's gonna take me a week to learn what to do exactly, I'll rather just revert to Android 8.

Thanks.

Comment: You should check whether your device supports version downgrade. Some devices get bricked which do not support downgrade.

Comment: Damn. I didn't realize... Resetting the phone to factory defaults doesn't revert to whatever Android it was on first boot right?

OMG I hate Google now.

Comment: No, it does not. Factory reset only deletes user data, not the system updates.

Comment: With "new improved recent apps list" you are referring to the recent list where you have to scroll horizontally and each app is displayed as screen in ~70% of the original size, side-by-side, right?

Comment: Robert: Yes, that. It's work of the devil, no exaggeration. It literally hurts my thumb to scroll horizontally that much, and hurts my brain trying to figure out who could think this would be an improvement. Some sadistic experiment this is. Pie has many unbelievably annoying features, such as the AI brightness which doesn't work at all, the artifficial notch without notificaton icons, but the recent apps list takes the cake.